# Can someone explain how this simple C character comparison function works?

Tags: c

I am very new to the C programming language. Im confused why the function takes pointers as arguments? From my understanding, it looks like the function returns the difference in character value of 2 characters, is this correct?

Heres the function:

```
int charcomp(char *x, char *y) { return *x - *y; }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It compares the ordinal value of the first character of each string (or pointer to char), so equivalent to `return x[0] - y[0];` in case of strings.

Comment: @Ja͢ck They don't need to be strings, they could really be just pointers to characters; though it will work with strings as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a C library idiom that a 'generic' comparison function takes two pointers to objects to compare and returns an `int` result that indicates the following:

- a negative result means the first object is less than the second object
- a zero result means the two objects are equal
- a positive result means the first object is greater than the second object

Since the negative and positive results don't have to be specific values (though -1 and 1 are commonly used), it's also a common idiom to use a subtraction to generate that result for numeric comparisons. That's what is happening here.

However, beware that subtracting two int values could lead to undefined behavior in certain situations where overflow could occur (that usually won't be the case when subtracting char types though). A simple `if`/`else` set of tests can be used to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This will compare the first character of two C strings (pointers-to-char).  If the characters are the same it will return `0`, otherwise it will return non-zero.  This can be used as a boolean comparator, as in:

```
if (charcomp("alice", "aarvark"))
    print("they start with different letters")
else
    printf("they start with the same letter");
```

Comment: why does it return a boolean, wouldnt char - char return a char?

Comment: @DanielJacobson:  char - char returns an int, not a char, but you can treat any integral type as a boolean in C -- any non-zero value is true.